# Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow. (After app update)

Tags: android, android-cursor

I get this error:

Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 64 columns.

and then followed by this error :

Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

This happens after reading from the database. Inserting works without problems, however reading throws this error. Also, this ONLY happens after the app has updated. So if you complete remove / uninstall the app and reinstall it, the app works 100%. But after an upgrading from a previous version, I get this error.

I believe there was a problem in the previous db and it is somehow not corrected unless you completely remove it instead of just upgrading.

This is my onUpgrade code:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SUBMISSIONS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SAMPLES);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SETTINGS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

And this is where I retrieve the values from the db:

```
String  SUBMISSION_id = cursor.getString(SUBMISSION_FORM_Index);
```

There is nothing wrong with the above code, as it works fine in all cases. Just when a user upgrades the app, then this happens.

EDIT

Here are the code where I'm reading fro the DB (This works fine, so theres nothing wrong with the logic here... it only gives an error when the user updates from an older version of the app)

I removed the unneccisary code:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_SUBMISSIONS, null);

    ArrayList<String> arraylist_submission_id = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            int SUBMISSION_IDIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SUBMISSION_ID);
            String SUBMISSION_IDIndexentryid = cursor.getString(SUBMISSION_IDIndex);
            arraylist_submission_id.add(SUBMISSION_IDIndexentryid);                      
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
```

And this is the logcat errors:

```
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   CursorWindow    Failed to read row 0, column 

0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 64 columns.
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.gideon.submissions.Screen_Main.doSync_form_c(Screen_Main.java:640)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.gideon.submissions.Screen_Main$9.run(Screen_Main.java:386)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
12:04:04.116    23988   #23988  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the code from row 640

```
String  SUBMISSION_FORM_C_IDid = cursor.getString(SUBMISSION_FORM_C_IDIndex);
```

if I ignore that line and remove it, it just gives the same error on the next line.

Again, this code runs with no errors, the problem only occurs after an update.

EDIT 3:

Here is the code that the above (row 640) is part of... I removed the unneccissary code:

```
databaseHelper = new Handler_Database(this);
Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getAllUnsyncedSubmissions();
String SUBMISSION_FORM_C_ID                       = "id";

//Retrieve data from DB for each entry that is not synced.
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{

Session.arraylist_submission_c_id = new ArrayList<String>();

do
{
    int SUBMISSION_FORM_C_IDIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SUBMISSION_FORM_C_ID);

    String  SUBMISSION_FORM_C_IDid = cursor.getString(SUBMISSION_FORM_C_IDIndex);

    Session.arraylist_submission_c_id.add(SUBMISSION_FORM_C_IDid); 

  }
  while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
else
{
 //other code
}
cursor.close();
databaseHelper.close();
```

Comment: show the code where you do the reading from database.

Comment: The code in your update doesn't really match the code you posted earlier. What is on `Screen_Main.java` row 640 - that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 64 columns.

The cursor does not contain any rows.

Check the return value of `moveTo...()` to make sure the cursor is pointing to a valid row before attempting to read values.

Comment: That is whats so weird for me, because I'm doing this if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        
{

            do

            {

Comment: Please post the relevant code along with the full stacktrace to get more help with it.

Comment: if(cur != null && cur.moveToFirst)